# Spark job on hbase data

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am new to spark and I am trying to get my facebook data from HBASE table with following schema:

[image: FB data schema]

I want to do a spark job on it as explained below. Following is my code to get the JavaPairRDD.

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseRead").setMaster("local[2]");
    sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
    sparkConf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb", "256");
    sparkConf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "512");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost:2181");
    conf.set("hbase.regionserver.port", "60010");
    String tableName = "fbData";
    conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60010");
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName);
    JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, TableInputFormat.class,
            ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class);
```

Now using map() of RDD I am able to get the JavaRDD for posts/comments/replies using type column:

```
JavaRDD<Post> results = hBaseRDD.map(new Function<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>, Post>() {
   //fetching posts 
   return post;
}
```

Now I have 3 JavaRDDs for posts, comments and replies. POJO Post has fields for comments and replies. So I want to add the comments and Replies to the post using parent post Id. How can I accomplish this with Spark?  Way that I thought of was to iterate through all posts, then iterate through all the comments and replies. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by making your 3 RDDs JavaPairRDDs, with the fields in comment as the key. You can then use the join method.

Assuming that the results and comments RDD are pair RDDs then you can just do:

```
JavaPairRDD<??> aggregatedResults = results.join(comments)
```

I do not know what type you would use for the combined objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by fields in comment? Any row in Hbase can be of 4 types: page,post,comment or reply. So if I make a pair RDD for post, its key would be postId and value would be all other fields. So msg column for post means post's message and for comment means comment's msg.

Comment: If you want to join two RDDs together you either want a cross join, which joins each entry in the first RDD with every entry in the second RDD; or you want to join the entries in the first RDD with a specific entry in the second. I assume you want the second, in which case you need to know which fields in the RDD are used to select the entries in the other RDD. These are the fields I mean.